# How to change pandas dataframe column's value base on another column's 2 adjacent values

Tags: python, pandas

I would add a new data column like "change" to a dataframe, I expect its value would be calculated from another column A current row's value deduct last row's value.

data example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 10, 100, 1000]})
df

It looks like
    A
0   1
1   10
2   100
3   1000

now, add a new column "change", new dataframe would be


    A      Change
0   1      0
1   10     9
2   100    90
3   1000   900
```

1. How should I do this?
2. If I expect its value sum of current row and previous 2 rows, how should I do?
3. I have many operations like this, do you have any suggestions where I can get a systematic learning of those operations. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a job for `df.A.diff()`

Comment: Should it be 900 instead of 990?

Comment: yes, 900, typo. Thanks, diff works! would you mind check 2nd question also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the shift method:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 10, 100, 1000]})        
df['Change'] = df['A'] - df['A'].shift(1)   
# Fill the first row with 0 since there is no previous row
df['Change'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

For the second question you can also use shift command:

```
# Calculate the change column
df['Change'] = df['A'] + df['A'].shift(1) + df['A'].shift(2)
# Fill the first two rows with 0 since there are no previous two rows
df['Change'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

For the rest of operations it depends, you can just implement different methods and the use apply function.